# Woocommerce - display all sold out products

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to write some custom shortcode to display all Woocommerce products on a page that have been sold. Suprisingly Woocommerce does not seem to include this by default.

I am a developer but not super familiar with Woocommerce, so I was wondering if someone might be able to point me in the right direction. I've got a basic plugin working. Does Woocommerce have a built in function that will return all products marked as Sold? Ideally in the nice little product thumbnail format that includes the price and a link to the main product page.  Or does that all need to be built up from scratch if I am returning it from a custom shortcode? Or maybe there is a plugin out there already that does this that I overlooked.

Comment: Here is a shortcode that seems to do what you need : https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-display-stock-products-shortcode/

Comment: Wow thanks!  I definitely did not see that in my searching.  Does exactly what I need!